# Firebase pods generate duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, xcode11

I need help to solve my duplicate symbols errors. It started after installing Firebase Analytics with CocoaPods.

The duplicate symbols were all (34) in:
/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appName/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb.build/Objects-normal/arm64/

pb_common 2.o; pb_common.o; pb_encode 2.o; pb_encode.o; pb_decode 2.o and pb_decode.o

After updating to Xcode 11.2 and installing Firebase 6.10.0 (was 6.11.0) 5 other duplicate symbol errors appeared in GoogleUtilities:

```
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppEnvironmentUtil' in:
/Users/abnormalsolutions/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/infood-agjvxotmgtevwrbdluxflosleqao/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GULAppEnvironmentUtil 3.o
/Users/abnormalsolutions/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/infood-agjvxotmgtevwrbdluxflosleqao/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.o

duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GULAppEnvironmentUtil' in:
/Users/abnormalsolutions/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/infood-agjvxotmgtevwrbdluxflosleqao/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GULAppEnvironmentUtil 3.o
/Users/abnormalsolutions/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/infood-agjvxotmgtevwrbdluxflosleqao/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GULAppEnvironmentUtil.o

duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibRemainingBytesKey' in:
/Users/abnormalsolutions/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/infood-agjvxotmgtevwrbdluxflosleqao/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GULNSData+zlib 2.o
/Users/abnormalsolutions/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/infood-agjvxotmgtevwrbdluxflosleqao/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GULNSData+zlib.o

duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibErrorKey' in:
/Users/abnormalsolutions/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/infood-agjvxotmgtevwrbdluxflosleqao/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GULNSData+zlib 2.o
/Users/abnormalsolutions/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/infood-agjvxotmgtevwrbdluxflosleqao/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GULNSData+zlib.o

duplicate symbol '_GULNSDataZlibErrorDomain' in:
/Users/abnormalsolutions/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/infood-agjvxotmgtevwrbdluxflosleqao/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GULNSData+zlib 2.o
/Users/abnormalsolutions/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/infood-agjvxotmgtevwrbdluxflosleqao/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.build/Objects-normal/arm64/GULNSData+zlib.o

ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

I have seen other duplicate symbols questions on SO and tried out some suggestions, but I don't dare experimenting too much. Deleting Derived data does not help. I also tried removing -Objc linker flag from Other Linker flags under Build Settings, as suggested here on SO. Didn't help either.

I'm now back with Firebase 6.11.0. Here are my Firebase pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

Please tell me if I need to post more details. I really have no idea how to deal with this!

Comment: Downvoted? What’s wrong with my question?

Comment: You downgraded your Firebase? *installing Firebase 6.10.0 (was 6.11.0)*

Comment: Yes, to no effect though. I tried to go back to when it was working.

Comment: lol. No, probably not. Not the downvoter but I think the issue was the question was very hard for us to reproduce with the given data. I've updated multiple projects and not come across that error.

Comment: Yeah, strange. But pod deintegrate did the trick, luckily

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Ok, so I came across a solution.

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Comment: Last two days searching for an answer and that simple thing did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it could help someone!

Comment: perfect solution!

Comment: @DanAbnormal how do you actually do this?

Comment: @Cypras  You use Terminal and run these commands in the folder containing your podfile.

Comment: Thank you sir. This helped me <3

Comment: Didn't work on my case. Is there any other solution ?

Comment: @SuatKarabacak, post a new question and describe your issue